# SQL - Update table for a unique ID with multiple entries if one entry has variable in question

Tags: update

I'm trying to update a table to fill in a variable to each row in the table if one row for the unique ID shows that variable.

I was trying to do the following, but it's giving me an error.  Appreciate the help!

```
update patient_encounter 
Set user_defined4 = 'DTC'
where person_id = (SELECT person_id from patient_encounter where  mrkt_plan_id = '489681B4-9D94-413B-95A0-C50D5964F340')
```

I want to fill in "DTC" into the user_defined4 field for any person_id that shows the particular mrkt_plan_id listed (which correlates to DTC) for any of their entries.  Each person_id has multiple encounters and I want them all to share the same market plan once it is listed as DTC once.

The error says Subquery returned more than 1 value.
Thanks!

Comment: Please tag your posts with the database server that you want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There multiple entry in table `patient_encounter` for a person_id, so you need to get the person_id with `top 1`

Try this

```
update patient_encounter 
Set user_defined4 = 'DTC'
where person_id = (SELECT top 1 person_id from patient_encounter 
                     where  mrkt_plan_id = '489681B4-9D94-413B-95A0-C50D5964F340')
```

**EDIT** as per comment, if you are looking to update all the record, use IN as below

```
update patient_encounter 
    Set user_defined4 = 'DTC'
    where person_id IN (SELECT person_id from patient_encounter 
                         where  mrkt_plan_id = '489681B4-9D94-413B-95A0-C50D5964F340')
```

Comment: That runs, but only sets 1 of the unique person_id entries to have DTC as the marketing plan. It doesn't fill it in for all applicable records with that mrkt_plan_id.  Do I need to run this as a loop to get it for multiple different person_id records?

Comment: @Reid one simple query will be  `update patient_encounter Set user_defined4 = 'DTC' where  mrkt_plan_id = '489681B4-9D94-413B-95A0-C50D5964F340 AND person_id IS NOT NULL;` but not sure what exactly table data are.